# add mapp laravel in route does not run when i use localhost

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, localhost, laravel-artisan

if I add the mapping in the route.php I run with localhost, I laravel project does not run. but if I run it with artisan serve the mapping goes well. Sample

**route.php**

```
    Route::get('/halo', function(){
    return "Hallo";
});
```

run in localhost :
 *localhost/myProject/public/halo*

Result :
 **Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException**

if i run with artisan serve my project runs well.
can you help me, what's wrong with this..
Thanks..

Comment: Too little information. What Laravel version do you use? Do you simple run url in browser or maybe send some form data?

Comment: v 4.2.
just simple run url

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Webserver configuration (nginx or apache?) you should enter a different URL. Try learning a thing or two about `virtual hosts`.

By default, if you use **php artisan serve**, your project will run at `http://localhost:8000` and you can then access the `http://localhost:8000/halo` route.

If you use **Nginx** or another webserver together with php5-fpm or something similar, it depends on your setup. You can configure it to show your project under `http://localhost/` or `http://yourproject.dev` or something you configure. You would not have to use the path `/myProject/public/` subfolder.

If you are not interested in fiddling with webserver configuration, I highly recommend using Laravel Homestead. It is a little bit of setup work (installing virtualbox and vagrant) but after that you have everything setup for you and you only have one super easy configuration file to use.

Hope this helps.